# Why bindable decorator is not respected when a custom element rendered with compose

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

It is possible to pass attributes to Aurelia custom element with `@bindable` decorator:

```
export class ItemCustomElement {
    @bindable model: Item;
}

<item model.bind="model"></item>
```

Why custom elements rendered by `<compose>` are treated differently, according to docs they need an `activate` method to pass data? `@bindable` is not respected.

```
export class ItemCustomElement {
    @bindable model: Item;

    activate(model: Item): void {
        this.model = model;
    }
}

<compose view-model="./item" model.bind="model"></compose>
```

From the custom element's point of view, currently it needs to know how it is going to be used, with `<compose>` or not. I think a custom element should be isolated from this external decision. Can we make `@bindable` work in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Elements rendered by `<compose>` have access to their outer scopes. So, there is no need to use `@bindable`. See this example https://gist.run/?id=fae6b9c9c2e3a608a60522392329bae1

Comment: In your example, how do you access someMessage property inside MyElement class?

Comment: I could access because it was "imported" using `<compose>`. When you use compose, the element can access parent's properties directly

Comment: Yeah, in the view HTML template. I'm asking about the view-model JS file.

Comment: `@bindable` is the preferred way to put a custom element attribute to a class property, so it is possible to access it with `this.someMessage`. I'd like to use it in the same way also if a custom element is rendered with `<compose>`.

Comment: you can use `parentOverrideContext` from `bind()` method. See the updated example https://gist.run/?id=fae6b9c9c2e3a608a60522392329bae1 This is the only way I have found, I am not sure if there is not an easier way

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see it as a solution. I need to have a custom element JS code independant on the way how it is rendered, with `<compose>` or not. I believe `@bindable` should work with `<compose>`.